# Monitor two baud rates

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, baud-rate, arduino-uno-wifi

I am using different codes which set different values of baud rate through the `Serial.begin()` function.

I have an Uno using `Serial.begin(9600)` connected to an ESP8266 ESP-01 module

```
SoftwareSerial WiFiBoard(2, 3);
WiFiBoard.begin(115200)
```

Both of them are printing and reading from Serial, but when I use Arduino IDE Serial Monitor, I'm only able to display the content of the `9600`... Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Also, when I configure both of them to use the baud rate `9600`, I still only see the Uno information

Comment: You can't have two different baud rates on the same serial connection. That is illogical.

Comment: My understanding is that by using the `SoftwareSerial` library, a new Serial connection is used

Comment: That is a completely separate serial connection. Nothing at all to do with the serial monitor.

Comment: Oh ! That makes a lot more sense now... So is there a way to actually monitor the two boards ?

Comment: Your PC only sees what the Arduino sends through `Serial`. If you want it to see something from somewhere else then you have to actively read that data from that "other place" and send it to your PC through `Serial`.

Comment: That makes so much sense now.. So I still can chose a different baud rate for the WiFiBoard, I can still write and read from it, but in order to display it in the serial monitor, I need to basically `Serial.print(WiFiBoard.read())` ?

Comment: In short, yes.  Better: `while (WiFiBoard.available()) { Serial.write(WiFiBoard.read()); }`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer can not see what is going over the WiFiBoard serial connection because that connection has nothing at all to do with the connection to your computer.

If you want your computer to see what is being received on that port you must read the data from that port then send it to your computer.

It doesn't (much) matter about the difference in baud rates (only that if one sends too much data too fast for the other to forward it you will lose some data).

It's common to use something like:

```
while (WiFiBoard.available()) {
    Serial.write(WiFiBoard.read());
}
```

That will forward anything received from the WiFi board over the serial port to the computer.